# Writable file location / Communication AutoPlay Media Studio -> Flash AS3

Tags: windows, flash, filesystems

I have an application built with AutoPlay Media Studio which needs to be able to communicate with an embedded .swf, built in Flash CS3 with AS3. The APMS application needs to send a filename to the embedded flash.

I've tried using flashvars but these don't seem to work from the APMS app. I've previously written the info to a text file in the app's folder so that both the APMS and the flash have a set relative path to the file. Now I'm tasked with making this work on a write-protected device, and I'm stumped as to where I could place the file and still be able to find it from the flash.

My first thought was the user's temp folder, but from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460469/how-to-find-the-path-to-the-users-temp-folder-from-flash-as3) I don't seem able to find that path from the flash. Where else could I put it and still have permission to write to it even if the user is not logged in as an administrator? The path needs also be in the same place on Win XP, Vista and 7.

Any other ideas regarding the communication are also very welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else winds up here, the problem can be fixed by upgrading to AMS 8 and using ExternalInterface instead of flashvars.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, Just upgrade to AMS 8. You should write some script in order to check the user system if he she had installed Flash Player or not. Notice that flash player is no longer supported by Adobe. I advise you to use material design algorithms if you want to make your projects look attractive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31016444)